# What is the name of the green cross safety flag used at construction sites?

Tags: words, word-requests

I have seen the flag flying at administrative buildings used at construction sites. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 安全旗{あんぜんき}.  Also you can call it 緑{みどり}十字{じゅうじ}, it is not at all unusual.